# Set multiple fields in a single case statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, case

I'm not as familiar with SQL Server 2008 and I haven't seen an answer to this question anywhere else. Does TSQL in SQL Server 2008 allow for multiple fields to be set in a single case statement. For instance:

```
case MyField
    when 1 then ThisField = 'foo', ThatField = 'bar'
    when 2 then ThisField = 'Mickey', ThatField = 'Mouse'
    else ThisField = NULL, ThatField = NULL
end
```

Since my condition doesn't change, it would be nice to set all fields based on that condition instead of using multiple case statements with a duplicated condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a JOIN onto a derived table or CTE

```
;WITH updates AS
(
SELECT 1 AS MyField, 'foo' AS ThisField, 'bar' AS ThatField UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS MyField, 'Mickey' AS ThisField, 'Mouse' AS ThatField 
)
UPDATE    YourTable
SET              ThisField =updates.ThisField, ThatField=updates.ThatField
FROM         YourTable LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      updates ON YourTable.MyField = t.MyField
```

Or for a `SELECT`

```
;WITH mappings AS
(
SELECT 1 AS MyField, 'foo' AS ThisField, 'bar' AS ThatField UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS MyField, 'Mickey' AS ThisField, 'Mouse' AS ThatField 
)
SELECT YourTable.MyField,  
       mappings.ThisField,
       mappings.ThatField
FROM         YourTable LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      mappings ON YourTable.MyField = t.MyField
```

Comment: True. Except I'm not doing an update. This case is part of a longer SELECT statement. However, this approach is noted for later. Thanks.

Comment: @Count - Well you can use the same approach for a `SELECT`!

Comment: This suggestion worked wonderfully. I put the case statements in the derived table creation and then replaced a joined table with the new derived version. This gave me the flexibility I needed and allowed me to not use multiple instances of a case statements in the body of the select statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, case only returns a scalar value.

```
ThisField = case MyField when 1 then 'foo' when 2 then 'Mickey' end,
ThatField = case MyField when 1 then 'bar' when 2 then 'Mouse' end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using CASE, you can only use that to get an output value, not to assign a value. You can write multiple update queries with WHERE clause to get what you intend to update.

Just saw, the answer from RedFilter seems to be way to update in one single query.

Comment: My code was poorly written. It wasn't an update statement, but a messed up "AS" syntax. More like: when 1 then 'foo' as ThisField, 'bar' as ThatField. But, it seems the answer is no. Sigh!

Comment: I agree with RedFilter. But in a complicated case statement, it would be NICE to consolidate the code instead of repeating the "when" clauses.